# MvvmCross Passing Value ViewModels(Portable) To View(Android and IOs)

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have installed Xamarin with pluggin with VS2013, and my application function with android and ios, in my portable Core I have my ViewModels in this case my file is OficinaViewModel.cs

> ```
> public class OficinaViewModel : MvxViewModel{        
>     private List<main> oficinas;
>     public List<main> Oficinas {
>         get { return oficinas; }
>         set { oficinas = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Oficinas); }
>     }        
>     public OficinaViewModel(ICrdDataService dbService)
>     {                     
>         try{
>             List<main> datosOf = dbService.GetAllMain().FindAll(p => p.element_type == "OF'");
>             Oficinas = datosOf;
>         }catch (Exception ex) {
>             var msg = ex.Message;
>         }                       
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In my project Android I need retrieve the value of Oficinas, but I need in variable not in xaml local:MvxBind, this value I would like in my file OficinaView.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle){
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.OficinaView);            
    SetupMap();
    //In this point I need retrieve the value of "Oficinas" from ViewModels
}
```

How I can retrieve the value of list "Oficinas" from ViewModels (Core) in my Views (OficinaView.cs)? project android

Answer (score 0):

I could solve with this:

```
var oficinas = (ViewModel as CrdMovil.Core.ViewModels.OficinaViewModel).Oficinas;
```

Comment: I think you can avoid the cast if you inherit from `MvxViewModel<OficinaViewModel>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var oficinas = (ViewModel as CrdMovil.Core.ViewModels.OficinaViewModel).Oficinas;
```

what is this ViewModel in your Case [(**ViewModel** as CrdMovil.Core.ViewModels.OficinaViewModel)]

i have a similar situation , where i get an exception.